# Rest API standard practice

Tags: rest

> Was a bit confused over a situation I am facing while developing a
>   rest API.
>
> I want to hit a POST request for some resource I have.
>   {contextPath}/{apiName}/{someResource} : POST
>
> The request body has some properties involved in it. e.g. :
>
> ```
> {
>     "property1": "value1",
>     "property2": "value2",
>     ....
>     "propertyN": "valueN"
> }
> ```
>
> One of the property in the request body refers to a persistence object
>   in my database.value in the request body is the primary key to that
>   persistence object. I have a piece of logic where I validate if the
>   persistence object exists or not. If it does I create a new resource
>   and return 201 created http status. If the persistence object is not
>   found, what status code should I send as a response? My first instinct
>   was 404. But the purpose of the API is to create a resource which is
>   not possible because of some persistence object in my database. Hence
>   I an not convinced with 404.

Comment: I'd say 400 - Bad Request. Since your API is expecting the persistence object in the request, must mean the request must be malformed if the object can't be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hence I an not convinced with 404.

I'm not either - [404](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4), very loosely, calls attention to the request-target, but here you want to draw attention to the request-body.

As noted by [T A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6436977/t-a), 400 is an acceptable answer.

> a client MUST understand the class of any status code, as indicated by the first digit, and treat an unrecognized status code as being equivalent to the x00 status code of that class, with the exception that a recipient MUST NOT cache a response with an unrecognized status code.

If you need to be more precise, the [HTTP status code registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) documents the standardized options.  The closest matches I see are [409 Conflict](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8)

> The 409 (Conflict) status code indicates that the request could not
> be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target
> resource.

Or [422 Unprocessable Entity](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2)

> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
> understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
> 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
> syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request)
> status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
> instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML
> request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but
> semantically erroneous, XML instructions.